# Updating JSP content into session using struts2

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2

Our application is developed with Struts2 and run on a JBoss server.

I have the requirement to develop a JSP page where the content of a grid will be displayed using `<s:iterator>` and `<s:property>` tag from a `List` (say `ArrayList` of person object) which is stored in session.

Now users can Add/Update/Delete the row(s) content generated by iterating session List.

For example if I have a list of size n of Peron object, and in JSP it's displayed as

> name age contact
>
> name1 24 1234456
>
> name2 30 45654634

and so on...

Users can Add/Update/Delete any number of rows and then finally can save.

How to approach this requirement ?

Comment: how about you leave a button "Update" there, when you click it you call another method of the Action (and of course another page) where you can modify the ArrayList, save it to database, and at the end of that Action you will be redirected to your original "display" method of the Action?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18874463/573032

Comment: @user1509803 OP want the to keep objects in the session, not to persist them, then after a few interactions with buttons persist all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dangerous... let's say that the power goes away, the session is not persisted everywhere.

So instead of updating the session n times and finally saving the data at once, you could simply save the data n times. But the requisite was thought to prevent too many access to the database (may be relevant with thousands of users), then you can use AJAX and Struts2-JSON-plugin like this:

1. Create an AJAX Action (in a `<package>` that  `extends="json-default"` and return a `<result type="json">`), that implements SessionAware, and receives a row from the JSP;
2. in the `execute()` method, read your List from the Session Map, add the new row, then return SUCCESS;
3. in the JSP, create a binding to call your AJAX Action (a click of a button in the row, the onblur event, whatever you like).
4. Add a button to call another Action (AJAX or not, but it should implement SessionAware too) to save the data in the database. That action will simply read the List from the Session Map and save it in the database.

This way the user can change page, coming back and finding all the data previously entered, and you will avoid a lot of POSTs of the entire page (AJAX + JSON is a lot lighter).